# newer version of Iceweasel on Debian Squeeze

Tags: firefox, debian-squeeze

I'd like to install as recent Firefox/Iceweasel as possible (for instance one that supports SVG images) on Debian Squeeze (stable). I don't mind installing testing packages if that's what it takes.

I have tried using http://mozilla.debian.net/, but it won't upgrade Iceweasel to 3.6 - it says that the package is already at newest version. Currently installed version is however 3.5.10. Any ideas?

Also, if anyone knows how I can use a newer version of Firefox/Iceweasel (ideally latest - FF7) without breaking my neck every time I update the system, I'd be very grateful. :) I have found [this tutorial](http://deviceguru.com/adding-real-firefox-to-debian-lenny/), but I am afraid I will have problems library dependencies if I go that route.

Note: I don't care if it is Firefox or Iceweasel, I would just like a recent version and auto updates (either debian or mozilla-style, whichever works). Please avoid flame war.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a link that allows you to install the latest Firefox without uninstalling your old version. The old version is renamed and you can still run it if you wish. The new version is installed into /opt and links are created so that menus still work. I've been using this on Debian squeeze a couple of weeks with no problems. It advertises automatic updates, but I can't confirm that automatic updates work.

[how-to-install-firefox-on-ubuntu-linux-mint](http://www.libre-software.net/how-to-install-firefox-on-ubuntu-linux-mint)

Comment: What about library dependencies, can I expect some trouble? I would expect library dependencies change with updates.

Comment: I can't answer that. I'm running version 7.0.1, the latest version so I have not had an update. Oddly it still shows as Iceweasel using the Help/About menu. Perhaps it brings all its dependencies with it?

Answer (score 2):

Just follow the instructions at http://mozilla.debian.net (add apt source, gpg key) and pin their package with higher priority like this:

`tail -n 3 /etc/apt/preferences`

```
Package: iceweasel*
Pin: release a=squeeze-backports
Pin-Priority: 900
```

Though I'm on testing/unstable/experimental mix, it takes precedence over anything else:

`apt-cache policy iceweasel`

```
iceweasel:
 Installed: 7.0.1-4
 Candidate: 7.0.1-4~bpo60+1
 Package pin: 7.0.1-4~bpo60+1
 Version table:
    8.0~b5-1 900
         1 http://debian.balt.net/debian/ experimental/main i386 Packages
*** 7.0.1-4 900
       500 http://debian.balt.net/debian/ testing/main i386 Packages
        50 http://debian.balt.net/debian/ unstable/main i386 Packages
       100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
    7.0.1-4~bpo60+1 900
       500 http://mozilla.debian.net/ squeeze-backports/iceweasel-release i386..
```

You can read more on apt-pinning [here](http://wiki.debian.org/AptPreferences).

Comment: I had to use "Package: \*" instead of "Package: iceweasel\*" to make it work, but it works now. However the package provided (3.6.23) is still too old, so I'll use W_Whalley's way... Still, thank you for the suggestion!

Comment: @johndodo: 7.0.1 is there (at least at mozilla.debian.net, see the output of apt-cache) or here is direct link http://mozilla.debian.net/pool/iceweasel-release/i/iceweasel/iceweasel_7.0.1-4~bpo60+1_i386.deb

Comment: yes, but not for stable... I can get 8.0 if I choose `beta`, but if I select `release` or `3.6`, I get 3.5 and 3.6 only.

Comment: just an update: I left pinning in place (forgot about it) and it messed up with my upgrade (multiple conflicts). So I would recommend avoiding this method. :) But thanks for your effort anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the output of my `apt-cache`:

```
iceweasel:
Installed: 8.0-3~bpo60+1
Candidate: 8.0-3~bpo60+1
Version table:
*** 8.0-3~bpo60+1 0
    500 http://mozilla.debian.net/ squeeze-backports/iceweasel-release amd64 
Packages
    100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
 3.5.16-11 0
    500 http://security.debian.org/ squeeze/updates/main amd64 Packages
 3.5.16-10 0
    500 http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/ squeeze/main amd64 Packages
```

It appears that I didn't need the pinning.